# Dual of a $C^*$ algebra valued continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space

Tags: c-star-algebras, dual-spaces

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$ -algebra and let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Consider the $C^*$ - algebra $C(X,A)$, which are the $A$ valued continuous functions on $X$. This $C^*$ algebra $C(X,A)=C(X) \otimes A$, where there is a unique tensor product structure is there since $C(X)$ is nuclear. In particular if $A=\mathbb{C}$, it is just usual $C(X)$. I would like to know same theories like $C(X)$ have been developed for $C(X,A)$, like the dual of $C(X,A)$ as regular $A$ valued measures, and $B(X,A)$ which are $A$ valued bounded measurable functions etc. Can you suggest any references towards this?

Comment: Check C*-algebras by J. Dixmier. (I think that was Chapter 10)